# Why is it that many class methods and interfaces are not defined in the JSR documentation

Tags: java

I was looking to start a java project that would allow me to look at just the specification and implement the solution in java.  I figured I would take a look JSR-173-Streaming-API-for-XML spec. and figured all class/Interface definitions along with class methods would be described in detail here.  This spec does not define every class and method as I thought it would.

I found the specification at the following URL  https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr173/index.html
in a .pdf file entitled jsr173_1.0.pdf.

The spec mention package javax.xml.stream so I figured all the API’s in that package would be explicitly defined in the specification.

For example, In the spec. I found the class javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory but it only mentions one of it’s methods newInstance(), nothing about the other 14 methods the class has.

Other interfaces and Errors like FactoryConfigurationError and EventFilter from the javax.xml.stream package are not even mentioned.

So my question is, if not in the spec. where does it specify all the other class methods and interfaces for this API.

Thank You.

Comment: How about the official [Java API Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/index.html) ? You can find [javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.xml/javax/xml/stream/XMLOutputFactory.html) there.

Answer (score 3):

> Why is it that many class methods and interfaces are not defined in the JSR documentation

First some facts.

- Java 1.0 was released in 1996.
- The JSR process was established in 1998 ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Community_Process))
- The first JSRs were producing public review drafts in around 2000.

By the time the JSR process was established, the core Java APIs were already mature.  They didn't need (or weren't deemed to need) significant revision, and so a JSR was not warranted.

People don't form committees and so on if there is nothing to do.  And people don't write and publish formal specification documents if they are objectively not needed ...

Secondly, some of the significant Java changes that were happening in the 1996 to 2000 time frame (e.g. in Swing, Collections) were being driven internally within Sun.  You would need to ask the people involved what the real reasons were, but I suspect it was a combination of the following:

- JSRs and other processes for producing specifications are done by achieving a consensus.  This is an iterative process.  The more people and organizations involved, the longer it takes.  In some cases, it would have just taken too long.
- There were probably people in Sun Microsystems  at the time who didn't want too much involvement of non-Sun people in the design process for some of the APIs.  For whatever reasons.

Finally, there are (probably) examples of more recent APIs or API changes where no JSR was involved.  In some cases, the changes could have been the result of a JEP.  In others, they could be a result of some internal Sun or Oracle decision to implement a feature or change without any (formal) external input.  They had the right to do that kind of thing (and possibly still do).

---

> So my question is, if not in the spec. where does it specify all the other class methods and interfaces for this API.

In that case, the specifications are the published (e.g. Java SE) javadocs.  And if the javadocs don't specify some aspect, then the published (OpenJDK or other reference implementation) source code determines what actually happens or illustrates what should happen.  You can download and read it.

<sup>(Note that API behavior that is not specified in (at least) the javadocs may be subject to change.  Historically, the Java team has been careful avoid changes that will break applications implemented against older (public!) APIs.  However there have recently been  exceptions to that; e.g. the deprecation and removal of Applet support.)</sup>

Comment: Is that a general question, or are you talking about a specific JSR?  In general, javadoc are *part* of a JSR's release documents, and will typically only available when the rest of the JSR's documents are released.  If you asking about getting early access to javadocs for a specific JSR, email the JSR's project lead or its experts mailing list.

Comment: I was just talking about JSR's in general.  If javadocs are part of a final JSR's release documentation then that makes sense because the javadocs explain the API in great detail.  I was thinking that there was some kind of .pdf file that has all the class and class methods defined and perhaps illustrated by UML class diagrams and sequence diagrams.